# How to change shapekey value and add keyframe with one button with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, shape-keys

I am trying to make a script that changes the value of 5 shapekeys, four of them to 0 and the fifth to 1, then add a key frame to all of them. I am new to python. I had been searching and looks like I need to make a operator for that and then attach the button to it..I'm confused.

Comment: All required functionality in here: https://github.com/p2or/blender-shapekeyextras